# Power BI Power Query filter main table with two tables based on columns from both

Tags: filter, merge, powerbi, powerquery

I have a table for invoices, which must be filtered for certain vendors and certain account numbers. The vendors and account numbers which must be filtered are both in two small excel files. How do I join them with the main table such that the main table is filtered for EITHER the account number or the vendor number?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are several ways to do this. Here is a solution that creates two lists of invoice numbers by filtering for the vendors and account numbers separately and then combining them into a single list that is used to filter the main table.

Here are the sample tables used (all included in the M code below):

*MainTable*

[image: MainTable]

*VendorFilter*

[image: VendorFilter]

*AccountFilter*

[image: AccountFilter]

Here is the M code that you can paste in a blank query:

```
let
    // Import sample tables and edit data types if needed
    SourceMainTable = Table.FromRows(Json.Document(Binary.Decompress(Binary.FromText("VY+7DcAgDAV3oabwB4dQZok0EfuvkWcLJNMg3p3Qie8rRFxqYSOcr18fgFldCNYILgdXLOEQeoiG1SlECyFLGJZSSmxxYbWU2Lx7wlJCl7j9QU+JLYb/glNiiUCWEuDzBw==", BinaryEncoding.Base64), Compression.Deflate)), let _t = ((type nullable text) meta [Serialized.Text = true]) in type table [Invoice = _t, Value = _t, Vendor = _t, Account = _t]),
    MainTable = Table.TransformColumnTypes(SourceMainTable,{{"Invoice", type text}, {"Value", Int64.Type}, {"Vendor", type text}, {"Account", type text}}),
    VendorFilter = Table.FromRows(Json.Document(Binary.Decompress(Binary.FromText("i45WCjNWitUBUiZKsbEA", BinaryEncoding.Base64), Compression.Deflate)), let _t = ((type nullable text) meta [Serialized.Text = true]) in type table [Vendor = _t]),
    AccountFilter = Table.FromRows(Json.Document(Binary.Decompress(Binary.FromText("i45WcjQwVoqNBQA=", BinaryEncoding.Base64), Compression.Deflate)), let _t = ((type nullable text) meta [Serialized.Text = true]) in type table [Account = _t]),
    
    // Extract lists of invoice numbers filtered for vendors and for account numbers separately
    ListInvoicesFilteredVendors = Table.SelectRows(MainTable, each List.Contains(VendorFilter[Vendor], [Vendor]))[Invoice],
    ListInvoicesFilteredAccounts = Table.SelectRows(MainTable, each List.Contains(AccountFilter[Account], [Account]))[Invoice],
    
    // Combine both lists of invoice numbers into one list and use it to filter main table
    ListInvoicesCombined = List.Distinct(List.Combine({ListInvoicesFilteredVendors, ListInvoicesFilteredAccounts})),
    FilteredTable = Table.SelectRows(MainTable, each List.Contains(ListInvoicesCombined, [Invoice]))
in
    FilteredTable
```

And here is the result where you can see that invoices 001, 002, 005, and 006 are not included seeing as they do not contain V3, V4 or A03:

[image: FilteredTable]